# Sort Range and Store Result in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a VBA function that accept a range, a key, and index and return a value based on it's index position.

The code look like this.

```
Function SortRange(datarange As Range, mycolumn As Range, position)
    Dim theResult As Range

    Set theResult = hasil.Sort(Key1:=kolom, order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo)

    SortRange= position.Cells(nomorurut, 1)
End Function
```

However, I always got #VALUE result. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: it's not clear what your function suppose to do. btw, are you going to use it like udf: `=SortRange("A1:C100",1,2)`?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a lot wrong here, or at least a lot of potentially wrong things.

First and most importantly, if you are calling this as a worksheet function, it will **never** work.  UDFs cannot manipulate the worksheet object (the `.Sort` method manipulates the sheet).

Also while you indicate the function accepts a range, a key (string?) and index (integer/long?), your function is accepting two range arguments and a third un-typed variant which appears to be a worksheet Object based on the later call to `position.Cells`.  So, the function does not appear to be accepting the arguments you expect it to accept, which may cause mismatch errors.

The following are also potential errors:

- If `position` is not a worksheet object, you'll get an error (object does not support this property or method)
- If `hasil` is not a global variable, or has not been instantiated, you'll get an error (object variable or with block not set)

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but probably the `VLOOKUP`, `INDEX` and/or `MATCH` functions already will accomplish what you are attempting.